# QTimer activeChanged signal

Tags: qt, qt5, qtimer

In the documentation of **[`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#properties)** there is a **Properties**-section, containing the `active`-property. 
This made me believe, there might be something like a `activeChanged`-signal, I could connect to.

For IMHO unapparent reasons

```
QObject::connect(m_timer, &QTimer::activeChanged, this, &MyObject::mySlot);
```

failes, stating `activeChanged` is no member of `QTimer`.

Basically, I want to do something, when the timer gets initially started (so not on restart) or finally stopped. When the signal `activeChanged` does not exist, has anyone knowledge:

- Why it is a property at all?
- If there are some other signals to connect to, to do this?
- Any way to hook in, and do something when the timer is started or stopped?

---

**test in main.cpp**

```
QTimer* tim = new QTimer;
QObject::connect(tim, &QTimer::activeChanged, qApp, [tim](){qDebug() << "Active changed" << tim->isActive(); });
tim->start(40000); // I want to get a signal
tim->start(100);   // I don't want to get a signal
tim->stop();       // I want to get a signal
```

Comment: Looking at the implementation, the reason becomes apparent: `Q_PROPERTY(bool active READ isActive)` - also it becomes obvious that there are now other signals to connect to. So I am left with the question: How can I achieve my goal without those signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own timer class and encapsulate QTimer:

```
class Timer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTimer m_timer;

public:
    Timer () 
    {
        connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Timer::timeout);
    }
    void start(int msec)
    {
        if (m_timer.isActive())
        {
            // Restart detected -> block signal
            m_timer.blockSignals(true);
            m_timer.start(msec);
            m_timer.blockSignals(false);
        }
        else
        {
            m_timer.start(msec);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the class `Timer` has the full control and knowledge of the `QTimer`, you can have any apparent behavior you want.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Encapsulation. I tried it with inheritance, thus failed :-)